# Why most of physics is somehow related to light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, everyday-life, quantum-electrodynamics

It seems that for the past 200 years, every physicist is concerned about light. For example : Newton's particle model, Young experiment, Photo-Electrict effect and Einstein's formula, Special Relativity (constant speed of light), Bohr's atom model (using Photons to emit electrons), Double-slit experiment from the quantum aspect etc.

My question is - What's so special about light and why do we care so much about it? I'm currently at 12th grade and all I've learned so far in physics (exept classical mechanics of course) is always related to light.

Comment: I think it's due to speed of light that it's the fastest traveler since it helps in generalization. If you know what generalization means here. Einstein used this term in his every book approximately and he meant to say that it's easy to find solution of easy, once hardest is found. That is generalization; to come from higher to lower level.

Comment: I had thoughts like this until taking a course in electromagnetism in college. It seemed like light was taking center stage everywhere. Eventually I realized it's more correct to think of $c$ as the important value, and light happens to be something that travels at this speed. For example, I have read that at high enough energies like what was present immediately after the big bang when the forces of nature were unified, all particles would travel at speed $c$.

Comment: Light is relevant because of those things you listed.  It shows up in many useful formula.  It's not like the physicists of the last 200 years decided to put it there, light turned out to be important and so it shows up in many places.

Answer (score 1):

Light exists in nature therefore physicists were bound to be interested in it at some point. But light is special in a sense. All we see, we see with light. Our eyes are sensitive to electromagnetic fields which make up this light. Furthermore, the main force which keeps the stars together is electromagnetism, which is the interaction of matter and light described by Quantum Electrodynamics (QED). Without electromagnetism, gravity would be the only long range force with nothing to oppose it (except maybe the Pauli Exclusion Principle but that a different matter) and matter would crush into itself in a very dense region forming black holes.

On top of that, Einstein discovered that the speed in which light travels, $c$, is an invariant quantity in the universe. From that you can build the whole of special relativity which all modern theories are dependent on.

Like this wasn't enough, General Relativity which is the theory of gravity, also relies on how space-time curves. Space-time, is the merging of space in time into one entity which encodes the relationship of space and time and how it transforms from frame to frame (this is where time dilation and length contraction equations are derived from). Space-time was found to be the correct description of nature, and its was discovered because light as a massless particle always must travels at $c$.

So to sum up, light is special because it was the first massless particle discovered. As described above, this led to a cascade of new discoveries in the last 110 years. We refer to the "speed of light" like light is special but its not. It would probably be better to talk about the "speed of *all* massless particles", but for historical reasons we don't do that. Thus, in reality, the actual reason in my opinion for which physicists love light is because for many years before the weak and strong interactions were discovered, electromagnetism was the main game in town together with thermodynamics which *also* involved light.

Comment: I believe that Einstein actually worked on explaining why light travels with constant speed $c$. After Michelson and Morley, everyone at the time knew that it had a finite speed. Also, I wouldn't put that the main force which keeps galaxies together is electromagnetism, but gravity itself.

Comment: No there is never a why answer in physics. Its the way nature works. Light is one of those massless particles that always travels at $c$. By keeping the galaxies together, I meant that its an opposing force to gravity which if absent, it would result in matter crashing onto itself to form black holes.

Comment: I'll rephrase: Einstein didn't discover that light travels at $c$, this was already known. Also, it is not electromagnetism that prevents the universe from collapsing into a big black hole, but the conservation of angular momentum. If you take a galaxy and ignore all the electromagnetic effects in it, then its dynamics would be mostly the same, because it is a closed system (approximately) and will conserve its angular momentum. Electromagnetic effects are not negligible near compact objects, but in general they are.

Comment: @QuantumBrick Perhaps i mislead you by saying galaxies. I should have said stars.

Answer (score 0):

Light is a rare phenomenon as it has no mass. Most particles have mass and therefore cannot act in the way that light is, which is to move at the speed of light. At this speed, due to relativity light moves at the same speed regardless of your perspective; no matter how fast you are able to move you can never catch up to light, and even as you try harder to do so light will always appear to be moving at the same speed away from you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the word light it would be better to use the word electromagnetism. Newton and Young were fascinated about the decomposition of white light into it colors and about fringes behind edges. Since Maxwell it was obvious that light was only a small part of the electromagnetic spectrum. Later were discovered the weak and the strong nuclear power. But in our life were only the two forces electromagnetism and gravitation we feel every day. About gravitation is only to say that we are subjected to it and that we speculate about the curvature of the space in dependence of masses.

About electromagnetism we know a lot and we use it every day. We know that EM radiation is the result of accelerated particles. Since Lorentz we know how to bind together the three phenomena moving charge, magnetic field and mechanical force. the resulting devices are the electric generator, the electrodrive and the magnetic coil. Laser and LED are EM phenomena too. For the understanding of chemical compounds it is helpful too to know electromagnetism.

There is a lot of physics where you don't need knowhow of EM. but every time you go deeper into some phenomena you end with it. Try it out.